# Split an uploaded file into multiple chunks using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, base64, compression, frontend

I'm looking for a way to split up any text/data file on the front end in the browser before being uploaded as multiple files. My limit is 40KB per upload. So if a user uploads a 400KB file, it would split this file into 10 separate chunks or 10 separate files on the front end before uploading it to the server.

Currently, I'm doing it by converting this file into a base64 formatted string, then split this string by 40KB which comes out to 10 separate chunks. From there I upload each chunk as with a filename of chunk-1-of-10, chunk-2-of-10...

When pulling down these files, I just concat all these chunks back and deconvert it from base64 into its file format.

Is there a better way of doing this? Is there a library that handles all of this instead of writing it from scratch? I'm not sure if the base64 route is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no need for reading the content into ram with the FileReader
using base64 will only increase the size of what you need to upload, base64 takes up ~33% more in size

Use [Blob.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) to get chunks

blob slices (chunks) will not increase the memory, it will just create a new reference to the old blob with a changed offset and a new size to where it should start reading from.

when `fetch` sends the data it will be piped directly from the disk to the network without even touching the main thread.

```
// simulate a file from a input
const file = new File(['a'.repeat(1000000)], 'test.txt')

const chunkSize = 40000
const url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'

for (let start = 0; start < file.size; start += chunkSize) {
  const chunk = file.slice(start, start + chunkSize + 1)
  const fd = new FormData()
  fd.set('data', chunk)
  
  await fetch(url, { method: 'post', body: fd }).then(res => res.text())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! One quick addition to this would be adding "start" to the second parameter of the slice() to get the subsequent chunks.

const chunk = file.slice(start, start + chunkSize + 1).

Comment: How would we output the server response?

Comment: @ParsaYazdani `console.log(await fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: fd}).then(res => res.text()))`

Comment: This worked for us, however, we had to make a minor adjustment, remove the +1 in the calculation of the chunk:

`const chunk = file.slice(start, start + chunkSize)`

Comment: Is it necessary to loop through each chunk and make multiple http request? can it not be done using file read stream?

Comment: I need to call three HTTP API endpoints when sending 1st chunk, 2toN-1 chunks and N (i.e. the last chunk). How to identify 1st chunk, 2toN-1 chunks and N chunk?

Comment: I think that in the for loop we also need to "add one" like so: `start += chunkSize + 1`. Otherwise we wold repeat the last byte of the previous chunk at the beginning of the next one. Or just remove the "+ 1" alltogether, effectively reducing the chunk by one byte.

Answer (score 4):

You could avoid having to base64 encode by using a `FileReader` and then sending as binary:

```js
const url = 'http://www.example.com/upload';

document.getElementById('file-uploader').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const size = 40000;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var buf;
    var file = document.getElementById('file-uploader').files[0];
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        buf = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        for (var i = 0;  i < buf.length; i += size) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('fname', [file.name, i+1, 'of', buf.length].join('-'));
            fd.append('data', new Blob([buf.subarray(i, i + size)]));
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("POST", url, true);
            oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
               // Uploaded.
            };
            oReq.send(fd);
        }
    }
      
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-uploader"/>
```

Comment: How would we output the server response?

Comment: Is it necessary to loop through each chunk and make multiple http request? can it not be done using file read stream?