# How to upload video files as chunks in angular (version 8)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, file-upload, chunks

I want to upload large video files as chunks to the server using angular HttpClient in angular with aspnetcore web API, as I am having issues with file size limit using multipart file upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tus Library

Another possible solution is to use the [tus](https://tus.io/) library which will chunk your uploads for you and allow uploads to be paused and resumed on demand - even if the client or server connection crashes the upload can still resume when the connection restores.

Unfortunately, the library must be implemented on the server-side and client-side which makes this cumbersome for supporting all server/client types. There is a community dotNet library available [here](https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet). For implementation in Angular, you can use the official [tus-js-client](https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client) library. The tus team also provide a live demo for you to test: [demo](https://tus.io/demo.html).

---

### Angular Client Example

> An example Angular client for file uploads to tus server:
>
> (The upload server used in this example is
>   https://master.tus.io/files/)
>
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tus-client
>
> Please note that a lot of the code implemented in my example is
>   available on the [tus-js-client](https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client) library. Here is another resource I
>   used for understanding [tus angular implementation](https://golb.hplar.ch/2019/06/upload-with-tus.html). I am also not affiliated with the library or the creators of the library. I just stumbled upon it in my search for robust upload technology.

Answer (score 6):

A possible approach to chunk video files in angular:

The HTML view contains an input of type file which triggers a function on the `component.ts` upon file upload. The component's function should validate the file type is a video and then chunk it into small pieces. An external service can be used to manage and send each chunk to the API. Then the backend should be on charge of receiving each chunk and merge it into a final file.

Here is a simple example that illustrates the programatic process from UI to API. The scripts are very basic but they show the flow. You should implement file validations, try/caching and other improvements to make it secure.

component.html

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileSelected($event)" />
```

component.ts

```
async fileSelected(file) {
    const chunkSize = 40000;

    for( let offset = 0; offset < file.size; offset += chunkSize ){
        const chunk = file.slice( offset, offset + chunkSize );
        const apiResponse = await this.apiService.sendChunk( chunk, offset );
    }
}
```

service.ts

```
sendChunk( chunk, offset ) {
   const APIurl = 'http://myapi.com';
   const data = {
       chunk: chunk,
       offset: offset
   };
   return this.http.post(APIurl, data);
}
```

A couple of references for native javascript with additional implementations: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121917/split-an-uploaded-file-into-multiple-chunks-using-javascript) and [link2](http://mylinuxtechcorner.blogspot.com/2015/03/upload-large-files-on-web-using.html)

Comment: what are the body type and response type of this request? and is there a way to change the file size limit when uploading the file?

Comment: That depends on what you configure on your API. Don't you have access to modify the backend service?

Comment: of course, I do, I need to know what is best practice of doing it.

Comment: That's good new. Then, on the API you should get the files and merge them. The response code should be 200 if success, so Angular can continue looping through the rest of the chunks. I posted a really simple example, but you could add a final call from Angular when all chunks are done to notify the backend. Also, on the service.ts you can add more logic to handle invalid API responses and resent chunks with issues for example.

Comment: how to merge the files on the API?

Comment: There are several ways to do it. I depends on which backend technology you use on the API. This question was for the Angular frontend and I've replied to that. If you want to know about the backend, post a new question on the right category.

Comment: I will try the angular part and check the answer if it works, thanks